# ASP checkbox 'checked' attribute always returning true

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have several `asp:checkboxes` on my webform which are filled in on page load, then returned on button submit.

the buttons are always returning the same as the server boolean behind them, no matter whether changed on the client side before being returned. After checking the clientID of the variables, they are exactly the same so it is not down to any hidden IDs or anything like that.

### ASPX

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    function slideTable(link) {
        $(link).parent().next().toggle()
        $(link).find(".navPlus").toggleClass("rotate1");
        $(link).find(".navPlus").toggleClass("rotate");
        var txt = $(link).parent().next().is(':visible') ? 'Minimise' : 'View all';
        $(link).find(".navPlus").text(txt);
    };
      function boxchange(box) {
        //Change has already happened at this point
        if ($(box).prop("checked")==true) {

            $(box).attr("checked", "checked");
        
        }
        else {
            $(box).removeAttr("checked");
        }


        var table = $(box).closest('table');
        var allChecked = $('#subjectsTable :checkbox:checked').length == $('#subjectsTable :checkbox').length;
        if (allChecked) {
            $(table).prev().find(":input").prop("checked", true);
            $(table).prev().find(":input").attr("checked", true);
        }
        else {
            $(table).prev().find(":input").prop("checked", false);
            $(table).prev().find(":input").attr("checked", false);
        }
    };
</script>

<div>
    <span  class="headerSpan" onclick="slideTable(this)"  style="clear:both" >
        <img class="logo-image" alt="HalsburyLogo" src="../images/siteStyle/logo.png"/>
        <span class="navPlus rotate1">View all</span>      
    </span>  
    <input onclick="chkHeader_click(this)" style="float:none; display:inline" type="checkbox" id="chkSubjects"/>
</div>

<table id="subjectsTable" class="subscriptionTable">
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 300px">
                <label>Art</label></td>
            <td>
                <asp:CheckBox onclick="boxchange(this)" ID="chkArt" CssClass="chkSubject" runat="server" /></td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

When a submit button is clicked, the value of chkArt is always the same. - upon checking, the clientID of chkArt on the serverside is also chkArt

edit: in the page load event the following code is present:

```
chkArt.Checked = //a bool from the database
```

Comment: Is the state of the `CheckBox` being changed in `Page_Load` or anywhere else in the page lifecycle events?

Comment: yes it is, i'll put it in the question now.

Comment: So, what do you think `runat="server"` is meant to do? Must you use it?

Comment: @user3558931: `runat="server"` is meant to make the control a server-side property on the page object.  If the OP is accessing the values in server-side code then yes, he must use it.  That's exactly its purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
chkArt.Checked = //a bool from the database
```

This code is in `Page_Load`?  Unless you're conditionally running this code (which you aren't in the question at least...) then this is being executed *every time* the page loads.  `Page_Load` is invoked whenever a request is made to a page, postback or otherwise.

So essentially your page is receiving the changed values, but ignoring them and just resetting them to their previous state.

You can conditionally check for postbacks in `Page_Load`:

```
if (!IsPostBack)
    chkArt.Checked = //a bool from the database
```

That way the initial state of the `CheckBox` is set only on the initial load of the page, and not re-set on every postback.

Comment: I have a page load check in my code above, sorry. left that bit out, trying to be as light as possible